# Reading Values from Choice Field of Sharepoint List

Tags: jquery, ajax, sharepoint

I am making AJAX call to a Sharepoint list which contains a Choice (checkbox) field. For this field the user can select multiple Countries for which a person is responsible.

[image]

[image]

AJAX call made to this list returns a href parameter containing a link for the related country values (TestContact(1)/Country) and not the actual values.

[image]

This means I need to make additional calls to get Country values for each of the records. So for 100 records I need to make 100 AJAX calls.

Is there any option (some parameter in Sharepoint Link) by which I can set to get Country values against each record in one single AJAX call?

Cannot convert this field to Single / Multiple lines of text as it will allow user to maintain any value (India or Indien / Germany or Deutschland / etc).

Sharepoint Link used in AJAX Call:
https://domain.com/sites/app/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/TestContact

Thanks,

Abhishek.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your request from:

```
https://domain.com/sites/app/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/TestContact
```

to:

```
https://domain.com/sites/app/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/TestContact?$expand=Country
```

In that case the *related* entries (`Country`) will be retrieved along with entries identified by the resource path (`TestContact`) via a *single* HTTP request.

**Reference**

[Expand System Query Option ($expand)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd541606.aspx)